# Ponytail palm Tree leaves turning brown

Tags: palm

My Ponytail Palm has half of the leaves that are totally brown.  I have cut them off but still getting more.  Am I overwatering?  Should I transplant to a bigger container?

Comment: Pictures please

Comment: a bigger container is not a good idea as these plants like to be pot bound.  Please add a picture

Answer (score 2):

Likely you have given too much water, yes. Compare your plant to the image on the wiki page for *[Beaucarnea recurvata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaucarnea_recurvata)* and if you have a greater proportion of dead leaves than that it is getting too much water. The plant is adapted to very dry conditions (native to dry northern Mexico) and needs to be kept like a cactus or a succulent, watered sparingly. The roots are perhaps the weakest part, since the leaves and trunk are supposed to be tough and hard.

If possible, remove the plant from the pot and stand the root ball on newspaper to wick water out of the soil which should help dry it out.

Look at more images found on an Internet search and you will note the examples appear to be growing in pots too small for them. This is good, as Kevinsky has pointed out in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are noticing brown leaves on your Ponytail Palm, it could be a sign of overwatering. Before transplanting to a larger container, make sure that the soil is dry to the touch before watering again. Overwatering can cause the roots to rot and lead to leaf browning.

If you have already cut off the brown leaves and are still getting more, it may be an indication that the plant is still receiving too much water. It's important to let the soil dry out before watering to prevent further damage.

If you haven't repotted your Ponytail Palm in a while, it may also be time to do so. Look for signs of overcrowding, such as roots coming out of the bottom of the container or roots that have wrapped around the inside of the pot. Transplant to a slightly larger pot with fresh, well-draining soil to encourage healthy growth.